# Labview - Check if TCP read buffer contains more data

Tags: sockets, tcp, labview

I've got a TCP Server that processes messages of the following structure:

`[ Msg. Size (2 Byte) | Msg. Payload (N Byte) ]`

The process is as follows:

1. Read 2 bytes from the TCP connection to identify payload size `N`.
2. Read `N` payload bytes and do something with it.
3. Close TCP connection.

To reduce networking overhead I'd like to piggyback multiple messages.

`[ Msg. Size #1 | Msg. Payload #1 ][ Msg. Size #2 | Msg. Payload #2 ] ...`

Obviously the processing loop must not close the TCP connection if the TCP read buffer contains more data (is not empty).

Is there any way to **reliably** check if more data is available in a TCP read buffer from within **Labview 2013**?

I could call `read()` again and  check if it times out. But I'd like to avoid this solution since it introduces unwanted latencies.

In the processing loop described above standard Labview TCP VIs are used (e.g. TCP Wait On Listener, TCP Read, TCP Write, TCP Close Connection).

Answer (score 0):

The client should `shutdown` the sending side of the connection as soon as it does not wish to send any more queries. The server should keep reading from the connection. If it detects that the other side has shut down the sending side, it can `close` the connection as soon as it has sent the final reply.

There is no need to wait for the `read` to timeout. A half-closed connection should be detected as soon as all data is read.

If for some reason you cannot support half-closed connections, you need some way to indicate the final request in the data that the server received. You can do this with a a special "I'm done" message. There are other ways.

By the way, you should not use the term "packet" to refer to application-level messages. You should use the term "message" to refer to an application-level unit of data that represents a single request or response.

Answer (score 0):

You can wire a zero for the timeout time. Then you do not introduce unwarranted latencies.

Comment: Then it will block forever.

Comment: No, it won't. Zero means check-and-don't-wait. Negative 1 makes it block forever. Quoting from the docs: "timeout ms specifies the time, in milliseconds, that mode waits before reporting a timeout error. The default is 25,000 ms. A value of –1 indicates to wait indefinitely."

Comment: The answer is actually correct. Wire 2 to "bytes to read" and 0 to "timeout ms". Then, check the error cluster for code 123 (timeout). If error 123 is set, a timeout occured, so no more data has been sent. If not, the function yields the two-byte message size. However, be careful to send the data in one send-call otherwise you might check for data just between two messages and get a "timeout".